# Elementor Form Showing Error While Submitting But i tired all available tweaks that are given in editor. please look into the matter

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to build a custom template of a simple booking form in wordpress using elementor and everything seems fine but forms not getting submitted and giving pretty general error and not a specific error about what's wrong. 
[From Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgTvr.png)
I tried changing range and minimum date but no effect whatsoever
[Form Setting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZePl.png)

Comment: Edit your question, please. Read the rules of this community.

Comment: What's in your console ? Right click somewhere -> Inspect -> open Console tab